# Using with and add to combine variables failed in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I met some problems when I am using `with` and `add` to combine variables in Django template.

Here is the variables that i pass to template

```
year = 2015
source = u'temp_dir'
```

In my template, `with` is below, but still `temp` return empty.

```
{% with temp="home/"|add:source|add:"/"|add:year %}
{{temp}}
{% withend %}
```

When I remove `year` from `temp`,Then `temp` value becomes `home/temp_dir/` (this is correct)

```
{% with temp="home/"|add:source|add:"/"%}
{{temp}}
{% withend %}
```

I have also tried transferring  `year` to unicode

```
year = u'2015'
source = u'temp_dir'
```

but it still it's empty, it seems something is wrong with `year`.

**Update 2015/09/02**

Here is my view:

```
## I will get a list of dicts from the db then do..
for result in results:
    result.year = unicode(result.year)

return results
```

**Answer**

When query from db, it returns a QuerySet object, and it not allow my program to insert new keys into each dict in the QuerySet object. But when I copy them into another dict-list, then I can add new key into it.

Old Code:

```
## I will get a list of dicts from the db then do..
for result in results:
    result.year = unicode(result.year)

passed_dict['results'] = results
return  render_to_response(index.html, passed_dict)
```

New Code:

```
final_results = []
for result in results:
    temp_result = result
    temp_result.year = unicode(result.year)
    final_results.append(temp_result)

passed_dict['results'] = final_results
return  render_to_response(index.html, passed_dict)
```

Comment: Using context['year'] = u'2015' works for me (Django 1.8.3). The documentation says that it the method fails, the result will be an empty string.

Comment: I don't get it. What's the difference between `unicode(year)` and `context['year'] = u'2015'`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass `year` as integer in the context. **You need to pass value of `year` as string in the context .**

You need to change

```
year = 2015 # passing integer value is wrong here
```

to

```
year = '2015' # pass year in string
```

The [`add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#add) built-in template filter in your case needs both values to be either string or integer for addition to be performed correctly.

> This filter will **first try to coerce both values to integers**. If this
>   fails, it’ll **attempt to add the values together** anyway. This will work
>   on some data types (strings, list, etc.) and fail on others. **If it
>   fails, the result will be an empty string.**

Here, you were passing one value as string and other as an integer which led to an empty string being displayed.

Comment: I tried to use `str(year)` to transfer, but still the same.

Comment: Where did you write `str(year)`?

Comment: In my view, there is a for loop to str(year) in dict, and then pass a list of dicts to template.

Comment: Please post the view code and the code for the loop in the template which you are using as the above code is working correctly for me.

Comment: It's seems the value will be changed, but the changes didn't be applied to template. It occurred in my other variables and template.

Comment: Sorry for replying late. Please post the code where you are passing `results` to template in the context. Doing `str()` or `unicode` should work properly. It seems the value you are passing is unchanged i.e. a number is being passed instead of the string  conversion which you did.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am not sure if I got the root cause, please see my update above.

Comment: Please post the code where you are passing `final_results` to the template.

Comment: added, please help to check, I am using `render_to_response` to passed the variables to template.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's bad idea doing this kind of work in templates. But if you must for some reason create your own [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters) and use `os.path.join`.

`os.path.join` will choose separator by platform (for linux `/` and for windows `\`).

Such a template tag may look like:

```
@register.assignment_tag
def build_path(*args):
    # or if you need only / as separator
    # return "/".join([str(arg) for arg in args])
    return os.path.join(*[str(arg) for arg in args])
```